# Datadog's rum view.url_path_group seems to group incorrectly paths in a web frontend application

Tags: datadog

I have a React.js frontend web application , and we use [Datadog RUM](https://stackoverflow.com)

In the link above you can see that "view.url_path_group" is supposed to group view URLs into groups, for example - "/dashboard/123/" and "/dashboard/456" will be grouped to "/dashboard/?/".
I would like to use view.url_path_group in order to create a Dashboard of the 100 least viewd path.

For example, let's say I have paths like:
`/books/123/pages /books/456/pages /shelves/abc/books /shelves/efg/books`

I would expect to have the following groups:
/books/?/pages
/shelves/?/books

but seems like that some of my groups contain specific ids, i.e - I may get
`/books/?/pages /shelves/abc/books`

Can someone further explain this inconsistent behavior?
Is there a different way to generate such a dashboard using DATADOG RUM?

Comment: Hi, I think your link is broken

Comment: Hi, I have run into a similar issue but with resources. Have you managed to find a solution?